# Como mapear uma tabela sem ID, usando as annnotaions do hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, annotation

Olá, bom dia. Tendo uma tabela que relaciona USER e ACHIEVEMENTS chamada USER_ACHIEVEMENTS, onde não possui ID, apenas o USER_ID e ACHIEVEMENTS_ID, ou seja, um relacionamento manyToMany.

Como mapear essa tabela no hibernate, sem ela possuir um ID?

Segue a minha classe Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="USER_ACHIEVEMENTS")
public class UserAchievements {

@Column(name="USER_ID", nullable=false)
private int userId;

@Column(name="ACHIEVEMENTS_ID", nullable=false)
private int achievementsId;
```

Ao executar o projeto, com essa classe mapeada dessa forma, o erro abaixo acontece:

*Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: No identifier specified for entity: com.poli.server.PoliServer.Model.UserAchievements*

Comment: Você tem duas formas de mapear esse tipo de relacionamento, pode criar uma entidade associativa, que é como está fazendo ou pode apenas mapear de dentro das entidades .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para criar um mapeamento Muitos para Muitos você pode mapear dessa forma as suas entidades, sem qualquer necessidade de transformar sua table associativa em um objeto java.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="notebook")
public class Notebook {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;
    private String serialNumber;
    private int ramMemoryTotal;
    private int hdSpaceTotal;

    //Relacionamento implementado
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy="notebooks")
    private List pessoas
}
```

Em Pessoa eu faço o seguinte:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Pessoa")
@SecondaryTable(name = "health_care", pkJoinColumns = 
{ @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "id") })
public class Pessoa {

    @Id
    private int id;

    @Column
    private String name;

    @Column(table = "health_care", name = "company_name")
    private String companyName;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name="pessoa_has_notebooks", joinColumns=
    {@JoinColumn(name="pessoa_id")}, inverseJoinColumns=
      {@JoinColumn(name="notebook_id")})
    private List notebooks;
  }
```

Comment: Oi, boa tarde. Eu também uso dessa forma, mas nesse meu caso específico, eu preciso mapear a tabela de relacionamento. Mas muito obrigado. Vou fazer dessa forma mesmo, enquanto não encontro o jeito que eu tava pensando. Obrigado

Comment: Nesse caso, você pode mapear uma chave composta, porque a @Entity te obriga a identicar um ID , seja com '@Id' ou '@EmbeddedId.'